# Attach Photos in SalesForce Site from android device using JavaScript and PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, salesforce, phonegap-plugins

I capture image from phone device and stored in my sd card using PhoneGap and Jquery. Now I want to upload images from sdcard to salesforce site and update the database. Please gave me solution how I do this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the FileTransfer.upload() method.

Comment: I dont know how to do this, please provide me the full source code how I perform this using javascript and jquery..

Comment: I can't write your code for you but check out http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer and http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/25/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap/

Comment: I try this but itdoes not update salesforce database, as i use server= "ap1.salesforce.com/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid='"; + record.Id + "'&parentname='" + record.CaseNumber + "'&retURL=ap1.salesforce.com/'"; + record.Id + "'"; where record.Id is the case where I want to upload photo